# Compartmentalizing JINJA templates

Tags: jinja2

I have an ~8 page site. At the moment I've got a common base template and then one quite long template for every page. Almost all of the "modules" (e.g a table, a comments table, a new comment form) are unique to their parent template, and need to be scoped to access all of the variables in that parent template.

At the moment a single page template might look like:

```
view.html
```

I would like to end up with something like:

```
view.comments.html
view.form.html
view.details.html
```

Where the code is - purely for readability - compartmentalized rather than one massive 400 line template for every page.

Can I accomplish this with Jinja? I just want a static include, whereas all of the block infrastructure looks to be designed for something a bit more sophisticated. How do people generally do this to keep their templates short and tidy?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after trawling through the documentation I discovered includes:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include

These have access to the global namespace, which is what I want. This is as distinct from import macros:

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import

Which I had previously used and wouldn't work here. Hope this helps someone else!